# TFS merge uncontrolled files and folders into TFS

Tags: tfs, merge

I'm taking code from a 3rd party, and modifying it. The 3rd party puts out occasional releases, as a zip file, I want to keep my branch, stored in Team Foundation System, up to date with theirs.  But I don't see any point of keeping their main trunk in my source control, just so I can merge it into my branch. Is there any way I can just do some kind of baseless merge from their files I download into my TFS branch?

I tried this:

```
tf merge /baseless "C:\localpath\to\third-party-release-2.0" "C:\localpath\to\mybranch"
```

and this:

```
tf merge /baseless "C:\localpath\to\third-party-release-2.0" "$/serverpath/to/mybranch"
```

and both tell me

> No appropriate mapping exists for
>   C:\localpath\to\third-party-release-2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The merge command applies changes from one branch into another.**

According to your command, you are trying to merge something from local to your server branch. This is not supported in TFS. You may need to check in your `C:\localpath\to\third-party-release-2.0` into TFS source control first. More info about `tf merge` command from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=vs.100).aspx).